# Find and delete all after a string in a file on every line

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file where i want to delete all caracters after the semicolon (;). In every line there is only one semicolon. Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
$variable = substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, ";"));
$file = "D:/test/php/liste_compte.csv";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = str_replace($variable, $content);
file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

any ideas

THX in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$csv=<<<HERE
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k;,l
m,n,o,p
HERE;

$output = '';

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);

for($i = 0; $i<count($lines); $i++) {
 $line = $lines[$i];

 // check for ;
 if(strpos($line, ';') !== false) {
  // if found then remove everything after that 
  $line = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, ';'));
 }

 $output.=$line."\r\n";

} // end of for loop

file_put_contents("file.csv", $output);
```

As required output is stored in $output you can do what ever you need

If you can provide us with sample csv data answer can be precise ..

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help. i have tried your script and it works, but to resolve my problem. How can i told him to go into the file and to delete  all caracters after tthe semi-colon and that process he repeat on every line. I couldn't make it work with your script.

Comment: did you test by assigning $csv with file_get_contents('filename') ?
and file_put_contents('filename') operation with same file name ?

Comment: Hi sorry, you are right, now it works, but there is still a little problem. I don't want to loose the semi-colon, only the content after them. If you can told how to protect the semi-colon at the end?

Comment: I thought that i found , but it was not. So if you know how to save the semi-colon at the end?

Comment: OK now. i replaced this `$line = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, ';'));` with `$line = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, ';') + strlen($marker));` Thank you very much!